# Databricks - how to write dataframe to SQL Server as Service Principal

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, databricks

I can read the data from Azure SQL as Service Principal using Python and Spark.

How can I write back into Azure SQL table the dataframe using the same tech?

This is the working code to read data:

```
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource_app_id_url, service_principal_id, service_principal_secret)
access_token = token["accessToken"]

Df = spark.read \
             .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
             .option("url", azure_sql_url) \
             .option("dbtable", db_table) \
             .option("databaseName", database_name) \
             .option("accessToken", access_token) \
             .option("encrypt", "true") \
             .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net") \
             .load()
```

Comment: Check out this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases#write-data-to-jdbc

Comment: All the examples on Microsoft docs are based on SQL Login. I am looking to run as  Service Principal.

Comment: Check out the link - https://www.thedataswamp.com/blog/databricks-connect-to-azure-sql-with-service-principal . Please evaluate and use at your own risk. Not my code and not tested - merely googled. Also note that it uses [adal](https://pypi.org/project/adal/) from PyPI which has been replaced with [msal](https://pypi.org/project/msal/). Since adal would not be receiving any further features, it is recommended to use msal.